# Cost Optimization Problem - on logistic regression output (Ypred)

Tags: logistic, optimization, prediction

To give some context, we are working on predicting Y for every auto insurance claim. The point is that if Y is predicted to be 1 for a claim, then this claim has to be assigned to a particular team (T-1), which has people with some special expertise. For each day delay in this assignment, there is an extra cost associated with man hour cost. Moreover, there is another cost on each day too. For every false prediction (FP) that the model makes, the company will have to unnecessarily spend some extra cost because such an FP would again be assigned to T-1.
Many of you would be knowing that there are 3 components to an Optimization Problem (OP) : (1) Defining Decision Variables, (2) Choosing an Objective Function, and (3) Identifying Constraints. Let us say hm is #mah hours spent on a claim on daily basis, and let us say that FPR (False Positive Rate) changes on daily basis.

Now, consider the following scenario: a claim (C-1) is predicted to be Y=1 on Day-1 and hence, should be assigned to T-1 on Day-1 itself to avoid any extra cost. Ideally, it would make sense to assign on the same day as day of prediction because doing so would reduce cost. However, let us say that FPR is 40% on Day-1 and 20% on Day-2, then cost associated with FPR would be much more high on Day-1 than that on Day-2. Hence, if we consider cost due to FPR, then it would make sense to assign C-1 to T-1 on Day-2 and not on Day-1 because combined cost due to extra man hours and due to FPR would be lower on Day-2 than on Day-1.

What we have written above is a basic understanding of cost optimization thing that we are trying to do. If you people know of some approaches that we can apply while approaching such a problem, please do share. It would be really helpful for our analysis.